# With Asciidoctor, how to exclude code between tags during an "include::"?

Tags: asciidoctor

I know how to get an extract of code during `include` in Asciidoctor by using tags.

You add tags in your code:

```py
# tag::function[]
def get_something():
    return "Smile"
# end::function[]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = get_something()
    print(res)
```

and specify these tags in your `adoc` file:

```
[source, python]
----
include::my_code.py[tags=function]
----
```

What I would like to do is to exclude some code by using this same tag mechanism.

My code would be like this

```py
def get_something():
    return "Smile"

# tag::main[]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = get_something()
    print(res)
# end::main[]
```

and the Asciidoc file could look like:

```
[source, python]
----
include::my_code.py[exclude-tags=main]
----
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this feature has already been requested and implemented in Issue [1516](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1516).

The solution elegantly implemented by mojavelinux is to add a `!` for tags you want to exclude.

Therefore, the solution would be:

```
[source, python]
----
include::my_code.py[tags=!main]
----
```

You have more details on the syntax in this issue including:

- using several tags (`tags=tag1;tag2`)
- using wildcards (`tags=*`, `tags=!*`, or `tags=**`)